# Which frequency to consider in SPWM for a transformer, the resulting frequency or SPWM frequency?

Tags: transformer, frequency, inverter

I am build an inverter with the EGS002 board, which has a SPWM carrier frequency of 23.4 KHz. In my mind the logic is that the transformer winding, material and size should be calculated using the carrier frequency, not the 60Hz that it will output since the variations on the magnetic field will be from the carrier frequency. Is this correct? Is the resulting frequency not important when calculating a transformer, only the SPWM frequency?

PS: Of course that there are many other factors when calculating a transformer, my question only focuses on the switching frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *In my mind the logic is that the transformer winding, material and
> size should be calculated using the carrier frequency, not the 60Hz
> that it will output since the variations on the magnetic field will be
> from the carrier frequency. Is this correct?*

That is incorrect unless you have contrived a new method which doesn't match the [standard sinusoidal PWM](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/cm-302-spwm-generator-inverter-design#:%7E:text=Sinusoidal%20pulse%20width%20modulation%20SPWM,controls%20and%20renewable%20energy%20applications.) as exemplified below: -

[image]

I've purposely chosen the slightly over-modulated scenario to demonstrate that the base frequency (60 Hz for example) is hidden in plain sight and, this applies to the under-modulated case too.

It might be an option to get rid of the transformer and work with a full-voltage DC bus instead. The higher-voltage DC bus can of course be produced with a transformer whose dimensions are determined by the switching frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So even if the frequency is 24.3KHz I should consider the 60Hz on my calculation? The frequency seems to oscillate. As of the alternative, that is a very interesting idea, I will take a look on that option

Comment: @AugustoMattos yes, 60 Hz will define the size of the core.